# SPARQL Find specific class(es) within a class

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I have RDF graphs many of them have property of class schema:SoftwareSourceCode I would like to find all classes of type schema:Person that are within that property.

Example of source in yaml that translates into RDF.

```
class: schema:SoftwareSourceCode
schema:publication:
- class: schema:ScholarlyArticle
  id: urn:pmid:24371156
  schema:name: "ALEA: a toolbox for allele-specific epigenomics analysis Bioinformatics (2014) 30 (8): 1172-1174."
  schema:author:
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Hamid Younesy"
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Torsten Moller"
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Alireza Heravi-Moussavi"
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Jeffrey B. Cheng"
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Joseph F. Costello"
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Matthew C. Lorincz"
  - class: schema:Person
    id: mailto:mkarimi@bcgsc.ca
  - class: schema:Person
    schema:name: "Steven J. M. Jones"
  schema:sameAs:
    - http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btt744
    - http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/8/1172.long

schema:author:
- class: schema:Person
  id: mailto:mkarimi@bcgsc.ca
  schema:name: "Mohammad Karimi"
  schema:email: mailto:mkarimi@bcgsc.ca
  schema:url: http://www.bcgsc.ca/author/mkarimi
  schema:worksFor:
  - class: schema:Organization
    schema:name: "Canada's Michael Smith Genome Sciences Centre, BC Cancer Agency, Vancouver, British Columbia, V5Z 4S6, Canada"
  - class: schema:Organization
    schema:name: "Department of Medical Genetics, Life Sciences Institute, The University of British Columbia, Vancouver, British Columbia, V6T 1Z3, Canada"
```

I stuck with the next query. It can find class schema:Person in direct property schema:author but not in schema:publication

```SPARQL
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT ?file ?SC ?name
WHERE {
  graph ?file {
    ?SC a schema:SoftwareSourceCode .
    ?Person a schema:Person;
          schema:name ?name .
    ?SC ?p ?Person .
  }
}
#LIMIT 25
```

A playground for the query is https://sparql-test.commonwl.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to understand the translation from YAML a bit more before you can predictably make queries.  Using some exploratory queries, I guessed that software may be related to something using the schema:author property.  That led me to this query:

```
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>

select * where {
  graph ?file {
    ?s a schema:SoftwareSourceCode ;
       schema:author ?a .
    ?a ?p ?o 
  }
}
```

The values of ?a are "mailto:" IRIs, and you can see in the query results some of the predicates and values used with it.  Now, if you wanted something other than authors, you can still do:

```
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>

select * where {
  graph ?file {
    ?s a schema:SoftwareSourceCode ;
       ?p ?a .
    ?a ?q ?o ;
       a schema:Person .
  }
}
```

That turns up a lot of results where ?p is schema:author, but also some with schema:creator.

Comment: I just new to SPARQL and RDF. So I've made some examples with foaf/doap/adms/schema. Now, I'm trying to figure out if I use schema, how flexible everything can be. At schema.org they say that schema:author and schema:creator are the same. So I just used both in different files.

Comment: So to translate into a language I would like to find all the Persons who involved in SoftwareCodeContribution. It can be as list of authors, contributors, developers as well as someone who involved in publication/s. So the only key to find all of them is that class schema:Person was used.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I come up with. I'm not happy about this solution. However it does things. So, It selects all the graphs that I have then finds all the objects with class schema:Person and all the projects with class schema:SoftwareSourceCode. Then I connect graphs with schema:SoftwareSourceCode `?file ?x ?SSC` and now the small trick that works `?SSC !schema:Thing+ ?P .` it means that there is a path from ?SSC to the ?P.

```SPARQL
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?file ?SSC ?name
where {
  GRAPH ?file {
   ?P a schema:Person;
        schema:name ?name .
   ?SSC a schema:SoftwareSourceCode .
   ?file ?x ?SSC .
   ?SSC !schema:Thing+ ?P .
  }
}
```